# Set HTTP condition for redirect rule

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

A have a redirect rule in my *.htaccess* that forwards agent from *A.html* to *B.html* using the following pattern:

```
Redirect 301 /A.html http://mysite.com/B.html
```

Since the `Redirect` directive requires to set the target host, is it possible to let this rule prevail only on a specific host? I have both a test and deploy domain, and only want it on the deploy domain. I can set HTTP conditions for `Rewrite` rules, but how can I for HTTP `Redirect`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to the solution that it cannot be done with pure `Redirect` directives. If it is needed to redirect visitor in certain HTTP conditions, must use `Rewrite` rules.

Comment: See my response for a way to do it with Mod_Rewrite in your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this, but you do lose the 301 redirect code.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host "myotherdomain.com" redirectthisdomain

<Files "A.html">
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from env=redirectthisdomain

   ErrorDocument 403 http://mysite.com/B.html
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

just put the redirect rule in the vhost config of your deploy domain. this way it will only be active for this host.

Comment: I use an external web space therefore I have no permission to the vhost config. That is, I wrote I need to solve my problem in `.htaccess`.

Comment: can you use rewrite? the apache rewrite doc has an example which matches your problem: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html#url

Comment: Yes, I know `Rewrite` provides solution for my problem, but I'm curious if it's possible using `Redirect`.

Answer (score 0):

My scenario is: two domain (domain.org and domain.info) pointing to the same site, and I want that .info is uses instead of .org

The site is written in PHP and at the very beginning of each page there is someting like this

```
if (stristr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'domain.org') === FALSE) {
    // do standard initial operations
} else {
    // insert here the code to rebuild the correct path and put it in $newpath
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://www.domain.info/$newpath");
}
```

In this way you inform both the users and the search engines crawler about your configuration.

Comment: @Irosa: You're right, but I do not use PHP but static HTML files. I'm looking for a solution with pure `Redirect` rules in my *.htaccess* but it seems so they are not capable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A quick example, if the visitor goes to dev.example.com/A.html then they get redirected to B.html. If they go to www.example.com/A.html then they get redirected to C.html; both with the 301 redirect.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST) ^dev.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) ^/A.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dev.exmaple.com/B.html [R=301]

RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST) !^dev.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) ^/A.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dev.exmaple.com/C.html [R=301]
```

You can read more about [Mod_Rewrite at Apache's](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) website.

Comment: thanks I know it. I do know `Rewrite` rules. I was curious if I can do the same with simply `Redirect` rules.